# How to render just one scene?

Tags: rendering, scene, render-layers

I have a blender project with 4 separate scenes which get combined in the compositor.  Every time I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> or press the *render active scene* button, all 4 scenes are rendered. **Is there a way that I can just render one scene?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you mean this, but I think you clicked the 'Render' button in the properties panel (which is the same as pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>). But if you click the small 'render' button in the compositor (Node Editor) it will only render that scene.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the scene you are currently rendering have compositor nodes?  If so: rendering that scene requires it to render all the compositor inputs.  You can deactivate the compositing step by unchecking the Compositing checkbox in the Scene > Post Processing properties.

You might also consider creating an entirely separate scene for the compositing, then render the other 4 scenes to stills.  Use the stills as input to the compositor instead of scenes.  This might speed up the workflow as you are tuning the compositing.

Comment: Yes, the other three scenes are combined in the main scene's compositor, so I can't just disable the compositor.  I thought about creating a separate scene, but that just adds a new layer of complexity.